# Error using Connect to receive event notification

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

I am just starting with the DocuSign API and Connect and have published a Webhook to receive event notifications. However, I am getting a 404 not found error in my Connect Failures list in the admin portal. This is the uri of my API method:
http://documentsigningapi.networxsolutions.co.uk/Webhook/DocumentSigned
I have set this in the URL to publish option in the configuration settings.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Xml;

namespace DocumentSigningAPI.Controllers
{
    public class WebhookController : ApiController
    {       
        public void DocumentSigned(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {            
            var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            var result = request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            xmldoc.Load(result);           
            var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
            mgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0");
            XmlNode envelopeStatus = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//a:EnvelopeStatus", mgr);
            XmlNode envelopeId = envelopeStatus.SelectSingleNode("//a:EnvelopeID", mgr);
            XmlNode status = envelopeStatus.SelectSingleNode("//a:Status", mgr);
            if (envelopeId != null)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:/inetpub/DocumentSigningDemo/Documents/" +
                    envelopeId.InnerText + "_" + status.InnerText + "_" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".xml", xmldoc.OuterXml);
            }
            if (status.InnerText == "Completed")
            {
                // Loop through the DocumentPDFs element, storing each document.
                XmlNode docs = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//a:DocumentPDFs", mgr);
                foreach (XmlNode doc in docs.ChildNodes)
                {
                    string documentName = doc.ChildNodes[0].InnerText; // pdf.SelectSingleNode("//a:Name", mgr).InnerText;
                    string documentId = doc.ChildNodes[2].InnerText; // pdf.SelectSingleNode("//a:DocumentID", mgr).InnerText;
                    string byteStr = doc.ChildNodes[1].InnerText; // pdf.SelectSingleNode("//a:PDFBytes", mgr).InnerText;
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:/inetpub/DocumentSigningDemo/Documents/" + envelopeId.InnerText + "_" + documentId + "_" + documentName, byteStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more like an ASP.NET question rather than docusignapi. Docusign will post connect notifications if it is a publicly available URL.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the API controller was not found, so I have now put my function into a web app instead of an API, which is now working.